# Library like Sizzle from jquery for XML

Tags: php, python, css, ruby, xml

This is not programming quesion, but: Are there existing libaries for parsing XML, that use CSS selectors like Sizzle (jQuery) instead of XPATH (in python, ruby or in php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one http://packages.python.org/cssselect/